# select condition in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am learning Pandas and how to select rows and columns from a DataFrame kindly check the question, answer and the result. To me my code makes sense I can't figure what I could have written wrong.

The question:
Create a DataFrame top_oceania_wines containing all reviews with at least 95 points (out of 100) for wines from Australia or New Zealand.

My Answer:
`top_oceania_wines = reviews.loc[(reviews.country.isin(['Australia ', 'New Zealand'])) & (reviews.points >= 95)]`
​

Result:
Incorrect: Expected top_oceania_wines to have length 49 but was actually 2

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 0):

[Picture from my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuHbP.png)

@ArchAngelPwn I found that I have extra space in my `reviews.country.isin(['Australia ', 'New Zealand'])` condition for Australia, I removed it and it good now. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

d1 = reviews.loc[(reviews['points'] >=95) & (reviews['country'] == 'Australia')]

d2 = top_oceania_wines = reviews.loc[(reviews['points'] >=95) & (reviews['country'] == 'New Zealand')]

top_oceania_wines = pd.concat([d1,d2])

top_oceania_wines

This gives the results as 49 returns
You can use "top_oceania_wines.count()"  to varify

Comment: Please do not post a separate improved version of your first answer. Instead, edit your original answer. Or you could delete your original answer and keep this one. Thanks

Comment: okay, thanks. but both can work the same in some instances

Answer (score 0):

top_oceania_wines = reviews.loc[reviews.country.isin(['Australia', 'New Zealand']) & (reviews.points >= 95)]

this works the exact match of rows

Comment: Please see my comment on your other answer. Thanks